# Ensure server is started in Chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am new to chef. I have a recipe where I need to start a server and then wait for the server to be successfully started.  I have this so far;

```rb
service "myserver" do
  action :start
end

execute "ensure myserver startup" do
  command "curl http://#{node['myserver']['http']['host']}:#{node['myserver']['http']['port']}"
  retries 5
  retry_delay 15
end
```

This doesn't seem right to me and seems like a common thing for chef scripts to want to do. What is the idiomatically correct way to wait for a server to start up?

Comment: Why does your service not block until it's ready? In most services, the init script or service runner will block until it's ready for requests

Comment: That's not the way the service is implemented. We have no control over this since it is a third party server.

Comment: Then it looks like what is solved here in the [Jenkins cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/jenkins/blob/master/libraries/_helper.rb#L273).

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out. I'm surprised there is nothing simpler.  Turn this into an answer and if it works. I'll accept it.

Comment: @StephenKing I don't find that the Jenkins solution is any better than what I propose above. It essentially does the same thing (open a url in a loop). The jenkins solution provides better error messages, but is much more complex, so I don't see any benefit in my situation.

Comment: You're relying on an external program. At least do the call directly in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

One other way is to use ruby block and use attributes to control the number of retries, sleep time between retries. This will also help in logging, raising errors. [This is a sample code performing a similar problem](https://github.com/bijugs/chef-bach/blob/copy_logs/cookbooks/kafka-bcpc/recipes/kafka.rb#L10-L33). Here when the service comes up an entry is made in ZooKeeper as a znode and hence the ruby_block is checking for znode_exists?. You can replace it with `curl`.

Comment: The link is broken,,